# DataReader returning null result, whilst executing the same query in PgAdmin gives back results

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to execute a query:

```
select d1.rtime, d2.rtime,
   (d2.time_on_auto - d1.time_on_auto) as delta1,
   (d2.time_on_zal - d1.time_on_zal) as delta2
from (select *
  from db_reso3f_operation_month
  where rtime = '2013-02-01' AND gateway_id = 11226 AND f2 = 2 AND f1 = 4
 ) d1 cross join
 (select *
  from db_reso3f_operation_month
  where rtime = '2013-03-01' AND gateway_id = 11226 AND f2 = 2 AND f1 = 4
 ) d2
```

When I execute it in a DB Editor (I'm using PgAdmin for that purpose) it gives back proper results. But when I try to execute it by using ExecuteReader() there are no results returned. The code for it looks like this:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand dbCommand = DBConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    string sql1 = string.Format(@"select d1.rtime, d2.rtime," + 
                  "(d2.time_on_auto - d1.time_on_auto) as delta1," + 
                  "(d2.time_on_zal - d1.time_on_zal) as delta2" +
                  " from (select *" +
                  " from db_reso3f_operation_month" +
                  " where rtime = '2013-02-01' AND gateway_id = {0} AND f2 = {1} AND f1 = {2}" +
                  ") d1 cross join" +
                  "(select *" +
                  "from db_reso3f_operation_month" +
                  " where rtime = '2013-03-01' AND gateway_id = {0} AND f2 = {1} AND f1 = {2}" +
                  ") d2",
                  device.GatewayId,
                  device.F2,
                  device.ReferenceCircuit);

    dbCommand.CommandText = sql1;
    using (IDataReader dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
          {
           while (dataReader.Read())
              {
             switchedOnTime += (int)dataReader["delta1"];
             switchedOnTime += (int)dataReader["delta2"];
              }
           }
```

I don't now what the problem can't be, aswell as can't find any information regarding if npgsql supports queries of such type.

Comment: First thing to do: stop using `string.Format` for SQL, and start using parameters instead.

Comment: copy value of "sql1" and execute it on Database editor directally, check is it working or not

Comment: Suggests one of your "parameters" is not what you think it is, then doesn't it. are they all numbers.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta I'm getting proper results in DB Editor (I've mentioned about at the beggining of my post)

Comment: I am not sure but give try to set dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta Tried it - still the same problem.

Comment: try with DataAdapter and fill dataset

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `dbCommand.CommandText = sql1;`, copy the value of `sql1` and try running that in DB Editor.

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried ExecuteScalar(), ExecuteReader(), String.Format, this approach ("...column = '" + parametername + "' ...."), Parameters approach and none of them works. My query is need to return 1 value only. I did a print out of the script and rand it in the DB Editor and it works. Have you solved your problem yet?